# Error while connecting MySQL Workbench SSH tunnelling with AWS EC2 (Linux -Free tier)

Tags: linux, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mysql-workbench

First what I have done so far

In AWS

1. In Security group given 3306 port access for all MySQL/Aurora:
   [image: Inbound config for linux instance]
2. Created a `.pem` key and saved it.

PuTTY

I am able to connect to MySQL (5.7) using PuTTY

1. Created new user: `create user 'admin'@'localhost' identified by 'xxxxxxx';`
2. Granted all the permission for DB:
   `grant all privileges ON db.* to 'admin'@'localhost';`
3. I am able to login using new user admin and new pass `mysql -u admin -p`
4. Changed `/etc/my.cnf`; added 
   `bind-address=0.0.0.0` (tried with and without):
   [image: my.cnf iamge]

MySQL Workbench

1. Tried SSH hostname:

   - a. x.x.x.x:22
   - b. x.x.x.x
   - c. DNS endpoint :22
   - d. DNS endpoint
2. Tried SSH Username:

   - a. ec2-user   (as suggested by AWS)
   - b. ubuntu
3. MySQL host name:

   - a. Port no 127.0.0.1
   - b. localhost 
     Workbench setting:
     [image: Configuration for Workbench]
     I have mixed all the possible combination of above. 
     but still getting this error:
     [image: Error]

Please resolve the issue.

Comment: I have done my best to format your question and clean things up a bit. Please edit the question to more clearly state the problem (don't just give a screenshot), and what you've tried to resolve it.